# Programatically Deploy List Item Layout

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, pnp-powershell, form

Suppose we created a list with a custom list form layout. Now, I want to move this list to a different SharePoint tenant/site. How do I programmatically apply the custom form laout?

[image]

**More details**
I am using SharePoint PnP Provisioning templates to export and import lists. Unfortunately, it does not seem that the PnP Provisining template contains list item form's laoyout.

Example of the Header JSON that I am trying to deploy programmatically:

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-borderColor-neutralTertiary"
    },
    "style": {
        "width": "99%",
        "border-top-width": "0px",
        "border-bottom-width": "1px",
        "border-left-width": "0px",
        "border-right-width": "0px",
        "border-style": "solid",
        "margin-bottom": "16px"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "align-items": "center"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "Mail",
                        "class": "ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-themePrimary",
                        "title": "Details"
                    },
                    "style": {
                        "flex": "none",
                        "padding": "0px",
                        "padding-left": "0px",
                        "height": "36px"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-24"
            },
            "style": {
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "width": "100%",
                "text-align": "left",
                "padding": "21px 12px",
                "overflow": "hidden"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "txtContent": "=' ' + [$Title]"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to apply these JSON customizations using PowerShell PnP?

Comment: The New feature of [custom list templates](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/07/12/custom-list-templates-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/) might help you

Comment: Thank you Ganesh. Is there a way to deploy JSON formatting for list items? I am trying to move it from tenant to tenant.

Comment: You are asking about list form JSON configuration, right? Or column/view formatting?

Comment: Yes, I am asking about the list item form customizations. Header, body and footer. See the screenshot for an example.

Comment: I have been busy this weekend, but I think you already got it. We need to extract the JSON from content type property `ClientFormCustomFormatter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Export list item form footer, header and the body**

```
$list = Get-PnPList SAMPLE_LIST-Includes ContentTypes
$contentType = $list.ContentTypes | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Item"}
$contentType.ClientFormCustomFormatter | Set-Content .\ClientFormCustomFormatter.json
```

**Apply List Item formatting programmatically.**

We need to to update the `ClientFormCustomFormatter` property for the list's content type:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -UseWebLogin -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SampleSite

$list = Get-PnPList SAMPLE_LIST_TITLE -Includes ContentTypes
$contentType = $list.ContentTypes | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Item"}
$json = Get-Content .\ClientFormCustomFormatter.json
$contentType.ClientFormCustomFormatter = $json
$contentType.Update($false)
$contentType.Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

**Sample Contents of the `ClientFormCustomFormatter.json` file:**

Notice `headerJSONFormatter`, `footerJSONFormatter` and `bodyJSONFormatter` properties:

```json
{
    "headerJSONFormatter": {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
            "class": "ms-borderColor-neutralTertiary"
        },
        "style": {
            "width": "99%",
            "border-top-width": "0px",
            "border-bottom-width": "1px",
            "border-left-width": "0px",
            "border-right-width": "0px",
            "border-style": "solid",
            "margin-bottom": "16px"
        },
        "children": [{
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "align-items": "center"
            },
            "children": [{
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                    "iconName": "Mail",
                    "class": "ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-themePrimary",
                    "title": "Details"
                },
                "style": {
                    "flex": "none",
                    "padding": "0px",
                    "padding-left": "0px",
                    "height": "35px"
                }
            }]
        }, {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-24"
            },
            "style": {
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "width": "100%",
                "text-align": "left",
                "padding": "21px 12px",
                "overflow": "hidden"
            },
            "children": [{
                "elmType": "div",
                "txtContent": "=' ' + [$Title]"
            }]
        }]
    },
    "footerJSONFormatter": "",
    "bodyJSONFormatter": {
        "sections": [{
            "displayname": "",
            "fields": ["Subject", "Sent", "Importance"]
        }, {
            "displayname": "",
            "fields": ["From", "To", "CC"]
        }, {
            "displayname": "",
            "fields": ["Body", "Archive ID"]
        }]
    }
}
```